# cmake for Java, how to specify main class and make jar file executable?

Tags: java, cmake

`Hello.java`:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello java");
    }
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Hello)

find_package(Java REQUIRED)
include(UseJava)

set(CMAKE_JAVA_COMPILE_FLAGS "-source" "11" "-target" "11")
set(CMAKE_JAVA_EXECUTABLE Hello)

add_jar(${PROJECT_NAME} Hello.java)
```

The generated `Hello.jar`'s MANIFESET.MF, don't have the `Main-Class` option.
Even though I've already add:

> set(CMAKE_JAVA_EXECUTABLE Hello)

Any idea how I can make the jar file executable?
I prefer not to write a MANIFEST.MF myself, or edit the one in generated `.jar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add *ENTRY_POIN* that points to the main class into the add_jar as:

```
add_jar(${PROJECT_NAME} Hello.java ENTRY_POINT Hello)
```

Comment: Works, and seems no need the line `set(CMAKE_JAVA_EXECUTABLE Hello)`. I've change the `add_jar` line to `add_jar(${PROJECT_NAME} Hello.java ENTRY_POINT Hello OUTPUT_NAME hello.jar)`, according to options from https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/UseJava.html#command:add_jar